# Insert into Java DB Compound Key with Prepared Statement Gives Error

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, javadb

I have two tables in java db, Alumnus and Certificate with a many-to-many relationship between them. So i introduced a third table  , ALUMNUS_HAS_CERTIFICATE to maintain a one-to-many relationship between the two tables and the new third table. the third has a compound key made up of the primary keys of the original tables. My problem is that 
I am unable to insert data with one duplicate key into the third table using prepared statement. 
Note : the third table has a compound key.

below is the SQL code for the tables.

```
 CREATE TABLE ALUMNUS (

ALUMNUS_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
 (START WITH 1 , INCREMENT BY 1),
 ALUMNUS_NO INT UNIQUE,  
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR (45) ,
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR (45) ,
 OTHER_NAME VARCHAR (100),
 RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS VARCHAR (300),
 MAILING_ADDRESS VARCHAR (300),
 EMAIL VARCHAR (120) ,
 TELEPHONE VARCHAR (25),
 EMPLOYEED BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
 JOB_TITLE VARCHAR (200),
 EMPLOYER_NAME VARCHAR(120),
 EMPLOYER_ADDRESS VARCHAR (300)

 );

CREATE TABLE CERTIFICATE (
 CERT_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 , INCREMENT BY 1),
 CERTIFICATE VARCHAR (300) UNIQUE NOT NULL 
);


 CREATE TABLE ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT (
  ALUMNUS_CK INT NOT NULL,
  CERT_CK INT NOT NULL,
  YEAR_GRADUATED SMALLINT
 );


   --CONSTRAINTS

  ALTER TABLE ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT ADD CONSTRAINT Alumnus_Has_Cert_Compound_Key PRIMARY KEY    
  (ALUMNUS_CK,CERT_CK);


  ALTER TABLE APP.ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT 
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (ALUMNUS_CK)
   REFERENCES APP.ALUMNUS(ALUMNUS_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;

   ALTER TABLE APP.ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (CERT_CK)
    REFERENCES APP.CERTIFICATE(CERT_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

the sql string

```
 String alumnusHasCert = "INSERT INTO APP.ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT "
            + "(ALUMNUS_CK , CERT_CK ,YEAR_GRADUATED ) "
            + "VALUES ( ? , ? , ?)";
```

code snippets of the prepared statement

```
    try (PreparedStatement stmAlumnusCert = con.prepareStatement(certUpdate) {
                                stmAlumnusCert.setInt(1, alumnusID);
                                stmAlumnusCert.setInt(2, certID);
                                stmAlumnusCert.setInt(3,year_graduated );
                                stmAlumnusCert.executeUpdate();
                            }
```

the error message from the netbeans IDE is presented below :

```
   IntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a
      duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by
 'ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT_COMPOUND_KEY' defined on 'ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT'.

at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source) at
 org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at wa_poly.UpdateData.update(UpdateData.java:192)
at wa_poly.MyJFrame.update(MyJFrame.java:1067)
at wa_poly.MyJFrame.updateButtonActionPerformed(MyJFrame.java:762)
at wa_poly.MyJFrame.access$1300(MyJFrame.java:65)
at wa_poly.MyJFrame$14.actionPerformed(MyJFrame.java:528)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Suppressed: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.checkForTransactionInProgress(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.close(Unknown Source)
    at wa_poly.UpdateData.update(UpdateData.java:212)
    ... 40 more
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still 

    active.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown 
    Source)
    ... 48 more
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a
  duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 
 'ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT_COMPOUND_KEY' defined on 'ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT'.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 51 more

  Caused by: ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key
  value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by
  'ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT_COMPOUND_KEY' defined on 'ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT'.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.insertAndCheckDups(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.doInsert(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.insert(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexSetChanger.insert(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.RowChangerImpl.insertRow(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.InsertResultSet.normalInsertCore(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.InsertResultSet.open(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
... 45 more
```

Comment: Can you share the sql you use for `stmAlumnusCert` we only can see the update statement, looks like you have an insert with a row that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the parameters in the prepared statement should be the same order in your SQL statement:

```
String certUpdate = "UPDATE APP.ALUMNUS_HAS_CERT "
        + "SET YEAR_GRADUATED = ? " //1 
        + "WHERE ALUMNUS_CK = ? AND CERT_CK = ? "; //2 and 3 



try (PreparedStatement stmAlumnusCert = con.prepareStatement(certUpdate) {

                            stmAlumnusCert.setInt(1,year_graduated); 
                            stmAlumnusCert.setInt(2, certID);
                            stmAlumnusCert.setInt(3, alumnusID);                                                                                stmAlumnusCert.executeUpdate();
           }
```

The wrong order is probably creating a duplicate composite key in your table.

PS: the question has been updated, this answer doesn't apply.

Comment: think so but just made corrections to the question. Rather the insert not the update that is giving the error

Comment: The exception says there is a duplicate key. Have you tried to run the SQL with the same parameters in the same DB through the console?
Is this the only SQL being executed in the entire transaction?

Comment: yes the sql query runs on the console with the same parameters